# como deserealizar un Json con el patron de arquitectura DDD

Tags: json, .net, asp.net-web-api, ddd

Tengo el siguiente codigo dentro del cual un cliente le hace un peticion Http de tipo Post con Json, Entonces mi pregunta es ¿Como puedo yo descerializar ese Json y extraer sus datos.
Ya tengo creadas las clases donde estan los tributos de ese archivo Json dentro de l Api. 
A continuacion esta el codigo de un metodo del controlador que recibe la peticion Post.

> ```
>   public IEnumerable<RespuestaJson> Post(Caso json)
>     {
>        return ProcesosService.DeserializacionJson(json);
>     }
> ```

Este es el fragmento al cual hace referencia el bloque anterior.

```
    public IEnumerable<RespuestaJson> DeserializacionJson(Caso caso)
    {
        Caso deseriCaso = new Caso();
        deseriCaso = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Caso>(caso.ToString());
        List<Caso> list = new List<Caso>();
        list.Add(caso);
        IEnumerable<string> en = list;
        return list;

    }
```

Comment: Estaba buceando por preguntas sin contestar y cuando me he topado con esta mira que la releo y no entiendo la pregunta ni tampoco qué tiene que ver con la arquitectura DDD. Si no encontraste la respuesta y te sigue interesando te leeré los comentarios a ver si puedo echarte una mano.